# I cannot detect a location inside a building

Tags: android, gps

I work on an indoor tracking project using android.I used Gps to detect location but it does not work correctly at indoor tracking

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: a little more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you GPS signal is bad there are 2 things you can do.

One is: improve you reception (e.g. remove the roof, good outside, replace roof with glass). Now this might be a little ... tricky

The other one is: use a different technique. Bluetooth tracking (BLE beacon) for instance.

You cannot 'amplify' GPS signal. The system works by finding out how long it takes a singal to go from several satallites to your phone. If you 'repeat' or amplify the system it is going to give false results. So you can not do stuff like "put an antenna on the roof", as all your locations would return the location of the antenna.

Comment: Just to explain this to the asker a little bit more-  GPS requires you to read signals coming from satellites.  Those signals don't penetrate concrete very well due to the frequency they broadcast at.  There's no way to fix this problem.  If you had hardware control you may be able to get a better receiver, but you can't really switch that out on your phone.  So you're never going to get accurate results via GPS indoors.

Comment: can i use access point to solve this problem ?becouse it is available in that building if yes can you tell me how to do that

Comment: I think you should probably do some research, in-building tracking is not something I can explain very easily without some research myself, expecially not in a stackoverflow anser, let alone in a comment. This is way to broad for a simple question online. I'm afraid you're going to have to do a bit of hard work :(